# Stealing political opponents information

Tags: halal-haram, politics

Is it allowed for a political party to steal a secret information from its opponents? The purpose is to win the election and establish more islamic laws in the legislation

Comment: What do you think? Would it be ok for them to steal your information, I'm sure you're not perfect, no one is.? Brother, be careful. Don't allow pursuits in life make take steps of Shytan as if you're sleepwalking. Theft is theft is theft.

Comment: What is your basis for "theft of political information" in quran/hadith ?